# What is the difference between data dictionary table and data dictionary views in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I was searching for data dictionary tables and i ended up in this page which describes "Tables Data Dictionary Views" with there description.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables014.htm#ADMIN01508

So what is the difference between  **data dictionary views** and **data dictionary tables**

please answer in simple way as an I am new to oracle I am using oracle 11g.
I just want to know the differences if there is any.

Comment: Hi there,welcome to StackOverflow,might be worth rather than linking in the article directly, that you should include the two items you want compared. It will help those answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you posted brings you to a page titled "Table Data Dictionary Views".

Everything listed on that page is a *view*, not a table.  For example, `DBA_COL_COMMENTS`, listed on that page, is a view.  `DBA_TABLES` is a view.

On this particular page, all the entries are data dictionary views *about the tables in your database*.  That is why the page is titled "table data dictionary views".  There is another, similar page titled "Undo Data Dictionary Views", which lists all the data dictionary views about the undo in your database.  Another page, "Cluster Data Dictionary Views" lists all the data dictionary views about clusters in your database.

A true "data dictionary table", which is not what your link shows, would be something like `SYS.OBJ$`.  This is a table that stores information about the objects in your database.  It is one of the primary data sources for the `DBA_OBJECTS` data dictionary view.  Data dictionary tables are low-level and cryptic (mostly).  Data dictionary views are more friendly and easily interpreted.

Also, for the sake of completeness, there are also "fixed data dictionary tables", which is beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: so  what developer are using the views  so most probably no body uses  the "true data dictionary table".  so u are telling that a "true table" look like this http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/sys_tables.html

Comment: Yes those are data dictionary tables.  Many developers use them as well as data dictionary views.  The views are more easily interpreted but sometimes going right to the tables is faster if the views include things that are not relevant to your particular query.  Use either as you need.

Answer (score 2):

As with all tables and views, data dictionary views are different ways to present data from the data dictionary tables. The dictionary TABLES are the main source of dictionary data. The same table may support several views. The views (which are calculated on the fly when they are queried, they are not STORED in the database) may present different data from the same table, based for example on the user who is querying the data.

Take the DBA_TABLES, ALL_TABLES and USER_TABLES **views** as an example. They draw from a single stored dictionary table; however, they have different columns, different WHERE clauses - to present different sets of rows - and ALL_TABLES and USER_TABLES will present different data based on who the user is.

Dictionary VIEWS may also present data from several dictionary TABLES in a single result set (through joins and such), or processed data (such as aggregates) - no different from the way views are used in a database in general, no special connection to them being "data dictionary" views.

**EDIT**

I was never curious to check the definition of the `DBA_TABLES` view. It's not hard to find it. Reading it, I realized that one thing I said above is incorrect. `DBA_TABLES` itself is not based on a single base dictionary table; rather, it is the result of the join of several other tables and views (which may themselves have non-trivial definitions). Here is the `FROM` section of the view definition of `DBA_TABLES` in Oracle 12.2.0.1:

```
...
from sys.user$ u, sys.ts$ ts, sys.seg$ s, sys.obj$ co, sys.tab$ t,
     sys."_CURRENT_EDITION_OBJ" o,
     sys.obj$ cx, sys.user$ cu, x$ksppcv ksppcv, x$ksppi ksppi,
     sys.deferred_stg$ ds, sys.imsvc$ svc
-- where
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the three types of data dictionary view is the result set.

USER_TABLES shows you the tables in the schema you're currently connected to.

ALL_TABLES shows you the tables which the user you're currently connected to has access to. This view has an additional column OWNER, to show the owning schema.

DBA_TABLES shows you the tables in the database. This view has an additional column OWNER, to show the owning schema. Only power users, such as those with the DBA role or the SELECT ANY DICTIONARY privileges.

Comment: thanks APC. now i know the basics of them  and that's enough for me

Comment: @johnjo - if you found this answer useful please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. Accepted answers improve the value of this site as a resource for future Seekers.